# Laravel Model fillable float always formated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a model where are fillable columns like price floats. How can I tell laravel to return always formatted values? Like:

```
$product->price // 8.00 not 8
```

I Know that I can use PHP `number_format()` function but I want not to copy it every line I will use it.

Comment: Basic read of documentation would solve you trouble with writing this question.

Comment: Are you receiving numbers/floats/decimals etc... in the right format from the database or is everything being returned as strings?

Comment: I get it as is. Of course not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```
public function getPriceAttribute($value)
{
    return number_format($value, 2);
}
```

Comment: I have done that but I got not formatted values again

Comment: Sorry it was my fault. I was passing values than to `abs()` function which rounded that numbers again. Thank you for your answer.